# Is it possible to select rows where the occurences of an id is > some value?

Tags: mysql, group-by, where-clause, having, sql-in

Given a table:

| userid | activity | location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | RoomC | 1 |
| 2 | RoomB | 1 |
| 2 | RoomB | 2 |
| 2 | RoomC | 4 |
| 3 | RoomC | 1 |
| 3 | RoomC | 5 |
| 3 | RoomC | 1 |
| 3 | RoomC | 5 |
| 4 | RoomC | 1 |
| 4 | RoomC | 5 |

Im trying to select only the rows where a `userid` shows up more then X number of times, lets say `>2`, so in the above database, only rows for userid 2 and 3 would be selected

Would something like this work?

```
SELECT *, count(*)
FROM marktable
GROUP BY userid
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This modified version of your query:

```
SELECT userid
FROM marktable
GROUP BY userid
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

returns all the users that appear more than 2 times in the table.

Use it with the operator `IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM marktable
WHERE userid IN (
  SELECT userid
  FROM marktable
  GROUP BY userid
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a3ebc87dfe062855690449ac13017c0e).

Comment: Thank you!  I made a mistake in that I didnt include an important point in the original question, I made a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72562010/is-it-possible-to-select-rows-where-the-occurences-of-an-id-is-some-value-or-t