# Is it possible to select rows where the occurences of an id is > some value OR the value of a column is > some value?

Tags: mysql, group-by, where-clause, having, sql-in

Given a table:

| userid | activity | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | RoomC | 4 |
| 2 | RoomB | 1 |
| 2 | RoomB | 1 |
| 2 | RoomC | 1 |
| 3 | RoomC | 1 |
| 3 | RoomC | 1 |
| 3 | RoomC | 1 |
| 3 | RoomC | 1 |
| 4 | RoomC | 1 |
| 4 | RoomC | 1 |

Im trying to select the rows where a `userid` shows up more then X number of times, lets say `>2`, OR the value of a column is `>2`.  In the above table I'm hoping for `count > 2`

So in the above database, the result of the query would give me userid 1, 2, 3

I've gotten the following query to get the instances where the occurences of `userid > 2`, but can I also somehow include the times where the column value `count > 2` is also true?

```
SELECT *
FROM marktable
WHERE userid IN (
  SELECT userid
  FROM marktable
  GROUP BY userid
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
);
```

Comment: If there was another row for userid = 1, like (1, RoomX, 1), would it be included in the results?

Comment: @forpas Yup, I think it should be included

Comment: This means that all rows of a userid should be included, even if the number of rows is <=2 and even if one of its rows has count <=2 (but exists 1 row with count > 2). Is that right?

Comment: Check my 2nd query also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another condition in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM marktable
WHERE count > 2
   OR userid IN (
     SELECT userid
     FROM marktable
     GROUP BY userid
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
   );
```

Or, if you want all the rows of a `userid` that has a row with `count` > 2:

```
SELECT *
FROM marktable
WHERE userid IN (
  SELECT userid
  FROM marktable
  GROUP BY userid
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 2 OR MAX(count) > 2
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4c319f2c2798d1dbf06585cedb764592).